# Remove line breaks from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

**Problem 1 :**

I have :

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want is (in a single line) :

```
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

**Problem 2**

Want to remove the outer `<TEST>` for each `<note>`

```
<TEST>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
</TEST>
<TEST>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
</TEST>
```

The desired Output should be (2 lines for 2 records:

```
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Please help me achieve this.Happy to provide inputs, if needed.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TEST">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="note">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sandeep kamboj! It worked fine for me. Can you please tell that how should I learn these things? Also I am not able to understand your solution, because I am new to xml &xslt. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
You may use this code for single line
```

Comment: For second problem your xml is not well form

Comment: Thanks @imran, After adding the line for omit xml declaration, it gave the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
By adding your root element you can use 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a/TEST/note"/>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Test/note">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do note that your request might indicate some desing problem, because serialization differences between XML documents are never taking in care. Also, the XSLT processor might not be responsible for serialization.

This **well-formed** input:

```
<root>
<TEST>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
</TEST>
<TEST>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
</TEST>
</root>
```

With this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TEST|/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="note">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alejandro! It worked fine for me. 
Can you please tell that how should I learn these things? Also I am not able to understand your solution, because I am new to xml &xslt.
Thanks again.